# PCA Sound Compression using Matlab

Tags: matlab, pca

I'm trying to build a sound compressor using PCA (Principal Component Analysis).

The input sound is always a mono-channel one, so the resulting matrix is a column matrix called `sampledData` in the code.

Compressing the sound requires the matrix to be transformed in a 2D one. So, one would need to group the samples the following way :

Here the grouping size is 3 with a sound composed of 7 samples

```
[sample1   sample2   sample3
 sample4   sample5   sample6
 sample7      0         0   ]
```

What does it change to have low grouping size (= number of columns wanted for the matrix) e.g. 10 or a high one e.g. 100 or more?

```
[sampledData, sampleRate] = audioread("soundFile.wav");

data = sampledData;
groupingSize = 10;  %Number of columns wanted from the data

%Make data size a multiple of groupingSize and fill with 0
data(end + 1:groupingSize*ceil(numel(data)/groupingSize))=0;

%Make data a matrix of x rows and groupingSize columns
data = transpose(reshape(data,groupingSize,[]));
```

Here is the remaining code I'm using for the sound compression. Unfortunately I have an error when `percentagePC` is less than 100, saying that the number of columns of the `compressed` matrix need to have the same number of columns as the number of rows of the inverse of `eigenVec`.

To illustrate, I use `groupingSize = 100` which gives me a compressed matrix of 100 columns and `eigenVec` is a matrix of 100 row and 100 columns. If I set `percentagePC = 90` I then get a compressed matrix of 90 columns (I keep 90% of the data that is most useful), so to be able to multiply both matrixes I theoretically need to reduce the size of the `eigenVec` matrix by 10 columns. Is this correct reasoning according to PCA?

```
percentagePC = 90;  %Percentage of principal component to keep

[rows, cols] = size(data);

%get eigenvalues and eigenvector by centering data matrix and getting its covariance
dataCR =(data-ones(size(data,1),1)*mean(data))./(ones(size(data,1),1)*std(data,1));
dataCov = cov(dataCR);
[eigenVec, eigenVal] = eig(dataCov);

%Sort eigenvectors (desc)
[~, index] = sort(diag(eigenVal), 'descend');
eigenVec = eigenVec(:, index);

%principal components calculation
P = zeros(rows,cols);
for i = 1:cols
    P(:,i) = dataCR * eigenVec(:,i);
end

%Number of principal components wanted according to percentagePC
iterations = ceil((groupingSize*percentagePC)/100);

compressed = zeros(rows,iterations);
for i = 1: iterations
    compressed (:,i) = P(:,i);
end

%Fuse principal components between each other to get final compressed signal
final_compressed = zeros(rows*iterations,1);
z=1;
z = 1;
for i = 1:iterations:rows*iterations
    for j = 1:iterations
        final_compressed(i+j-1,1) = P(z,j);
    end
    z = z + 1;
end

% Decompression of compressed signal
decompressed = compressed * (eigenVec^(-1)); % /!\ ERROR IS HERE /!\
[rowsD,colsD] = size(decompressed);

final_decompressed = zeros(rowsD*colsD,1);
z = 1;
for i = 1:colsD:rowsD*colsD
    for j = 1:colsD
        final_decompressed(i+j-1,1) = decompressed(z,j);
     end
     z = z + 1;
end


filenameC = fullfile('compress.wav');
filenameD = fullfile('decompress.wav');

audiowrite(filenameC, final_compressed/max(abs(final_compressed)), round(sampleRate/(groupingSize/iterations)));
audiowrite(filenameD, decompressed, sampleRate);
```

Comment: How are we meant to validate your code without any validation criteria? Why do you have doubts? What answer are you expecting here? Please produce a [mcve], this should help you debug the issue, and if you still have concerns then sharing that [mcve] in an [edit] shows us the *specific* problem. Perhaps you're looking for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/? Note they will also require a [mcve]

Comment: @Wolfie, I see your point. I guess someone with matlab experience and a proper understanding of PCA would understand the code and know if there is a mistake in the logic behind what I've coded. I am unable to do so with my limited knowledge of it, and I've been doing my research. I've looked at some clean code for image compression using PCA, but I am unable to reproduce something similar e.g [link](https://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2011/07/pca-and-image-compression-with-numpy.html?fbclid=IwAR05ENJo01h0yIrwLDZHj4vvNns6Myc93d0Pj1dgqzxNoawInl_c0QhZNIQ)

Comment: You are overly optimistic about how much time someone is going to spend (for free) to read, understand, and advise you how to improve *your* code without a [mcve], expected results for given inputs, or at the very least the mathematics you are trying to implement.

Comment: @Wolfie, in that case, i'll ask a simple question. The input is a mono-channel sound which is read and returns a column matrix. To apply PCA to compress the sound, we need to transform the column matrix into a I*J matrix (J = `groupingSize` at the top of the code). What does it change to have a high or a low grouping size when applying PCA ?

Comment: I've edited the question, but I guess it's more a stackexchange question now

Comment: PCA = principal component analysis? I am wondering if you have erased the PCA part in your question & code

Comment: I have, I'll put it right back up